# How can I pass data into MonoTouch.Dialog's delegates?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Given the following code, how can I pass data from "First Name", "Last Name", etc. into my method `BookASession.SendMessage();`?

```
RootElement CreateBookASessionRoot() 
{
    return new RootElement("Book a Session") {
        new Section() {
            new EntryElement("First Name", "First Name", ""),
            new EntryElement("Last Name", "Last Name", ""),
            new EntryElement("Email", "Email", "") { KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress },
            new DateElement("Event Date", DateTime.Now),
            new RootElement ("Type of Shoot", new RadioGroup (0)){
                    new Section (){
                        new RadioElement("Wedding"),
                    new RadioElement("Portrait"),
                    new RadioElement("Boudoir"),
                    new RadioElement("Other")
                    }
            } ,
            new EntryElement("Message", "Message", "")
        } ,
        new Section () {
            new StringElement("Send", delegate { BookASession.SendMessage(); } )
        }
    };                      
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way i like to accomplish this is by keeping references to my input elements. This way i can easily fetch their input values without having to search through the entire element tree. I'm doing so by encapsulating the creation logic for a particular screen in a separate clase, like this:

```
public class BookASessionScreen
{
    private RootElement _root = null;

    private EntryElement _firstName = null;

    private EntryElement _lastName = null;

    private EntryElement _email = null;

    private DateElement _date = null;

    private RootElement _typeOfShoot = null;

    private EntryElement _message = null;

    private void CreateRoot()
    {
        _firstName = new EntryElement("First Name", "First Name", "");
        _lastName = _firstName = new EntryElement("First Name", "First Name", "");
        _email = new EntryElement("Email", "Email", "") { KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress };
        _date = new DateElement("Event Date", DateTime.Now);
        _typeOfShoot = new RootElement ("Type of Shoot", new RadioGroup (0)){
            new Section () {
                new RadioElement("Wedding"),
                new RadioElement("Portrait"),
                new RadioElement("Boudoir"),
                new RadioElement("Other")
            }
        };
        _message = new EntryElement("Message", "Message", "");

        _root = new RootElement("Book a Session") {
            new Section() {
                _firstName,
                _lastName,
                _email,
                _date,
                _typeOfShoot,
                _message
            } ,
            new Section () {
                new StringElement("Send", delegate { 
                    //BookASession.SendMessage(_firstName.Value, _lastName.Value, ...)
                })
            }
        };
    }

    public RootElement Root 
    {
        get {
            if (_root == null) {
                CreateRoot();
            }
            return _root;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to decouple the form processing logic by having the class expose an event, like this:

1 - Create a class that will hold the event data, extending EventArgs:

```
public class BookASessionArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

2 - Declare your event in BookASessionScreen:

```
public event EventHandler BookASession;
```

3 - Fire the event in your delegate

```
if (BookASession != null) {
    BookASession(this, new BookASessionArgs() {
        FirstName = _firstName.Value,
        LastName = _lastName.Value
        //..
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Wondering if you would know why the value properties aren't getting set until I explicitly move away from a field (blur, take focus off, etc.).  For example, if I am filling in my Message field and click "Send" while I still have focus on the Message field, it's value doesn't get set.  Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman Actually it's something i forgot to mention. I do seem to encounter a similar problem, where i could not immediately get hold of the values and while i couldn't find an explanation for this (could be a bug?), i was able to get around it by calling field.FetchValue() before trying to retrieve it

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  At what level would I include a background image?  I want to inject an image behind all controls.

Comment: That could be done at the DialogViewController level. One simple way to do it is to have your view controller extend DialogViewContoller and override LoadView. In LoadView you can create your root element (Root = new BookASessionScreeen().Root) and set the background view after that (TableView.BackgroundView = ...). If you don't mind i guess i could post a separate answer to this question with some sample source code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the value properties not getting updated can be solved by calling the method ResignFirstResponder on the element that has focus. I guess this is something iOS specific.