# Monotouch.dialog EntryElement not being updated after editing

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using this code to create the dialog:

```
SettingsDialog settingDialog = new SettingsDialog ();
RootElement dialog = settingDialog.CreateDialog ();
DialogViewController dv = new DialogViewController (dialog, true);
dv.ViewDissapearing += delegate(object sender1, EventArgs e1) {
  // update the values
  Config.VendorId = settingDialog.VendorId;
} ;
NavigationController.PushViewController (dv, true);
```

Ths is the code for the SettingsDialogClass

```
public class SettingsDialog
{
  private EntryElement idElement;
  public RootElement CreateDialog ()
  {
    idElement = new EntryElement ("Vendor Id", string.Empty, Config.VendorId.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)){ KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad };

  element = new RootElement ("Configuration"){
  new Section (){
    idElement
   } ,
  ...
}

public string VendorId {
get {
  return idElement.Value;
 }
}
```

The problem is that the above property ALWAYS returns the old value, it never gets updated.
Any idea why?

Thank,
Ignacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, this thread had the key to it

[How can I pass data into MonoTouch.Dialog's delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410090/how-can-i-pass-data-into-monotouch-dialogs-delegates)

this line:
i was able to get around it by calling field.FetchValue() before trying to retrieve it

So I modified the property as

```
public string VendorId {
get {
   idElement.FetchValue();
   return idElement.Value;
 }
}
```